# Removing file extension from filename with file handle as input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code `f = open('01-01-2017.csv')`

From `f` variable, I need to remove the ".csv" and set the remaining "01-01-2017" to a variable called "date". what is the best way to accomplish this

Comment: `date = os.path.splitext('01-01-2017.csv')[0]` should do it.

Comment: you could use split  `date='01-01-2017.csv'.split('.')[0]`

Comment: I need to reference the variable f in my code since the file name could be changed at any time. your solutions worked with date = '01-01-2017.csv' but do not seem to work with the variable f @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: that's why your question should be more specific. Editing & Reopening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just retrieve the name of the file using `f.name` and apply `os.path.splitext`, keep the left part:

```
import os
date = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f.name))[0]
```

(I've used `os.path.basename` in case the file has an absolute path)